# Error handling Power Query refresh with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a VBA code that refreshes my data connections twice and then calculates the workbook. I added On Error Resume Next, but when there is an error with the query refreshing it ignores my VBA error handling and shows an error saying "Unexpected Error, Something went wrong. If the problem continues, please restart Excel." After i click cancel it continues with my code but the one query that caused the error still shows its running even though the other queries ran after it. I turned off background refresh on all connections already and i am just trying to find some VBA code where i can handle the error with power query.

Eventually i would want my code to cancel the query that caused the error and refresh it individually after all the code is done.

How do we handle errors in power query with VBA?

Current code:

```
On Error Resume Next 
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 
ActiveWorkbook.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: I think I would need to see your code to help with this. Could you add it to the question?

Comment: Error handling in Power Query should be handled in Power Query, not VBA. However if something is going wrong enough it's causing a message like that, it's likely something that needs to be addressed and not ignored (I'll sometimes see a message like that if Power Query is capping out the available system memory).

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` will capture errors thrown by the VBA compiler, not the Excel application.

Comment: the code is pretty simple

On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Comment: @TimQ Why do you have 2 `RefreshAll`s in there?

Comment: Because power query stinks and sometimes doesn't fully update on one refresh. This is just a example of the code, i have a Application.Wait() line in between the two refresh statements. When the error comes it occurs on both cycles of the refresh code

Comment: Even if the query refresh is set to Background, I believe you still need the `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone` call to make the VBA code wait. That could also explain why you're getting the error - it may be because you're calling a refresh on queries that are already being refreshed....

Comment: I have the same code that i run on 20+ different files daily, and only some give the error. I researched before and the code waits for the queries to finish executing before it calculates the workbook

Answer (score 0):

Within Power Query you can wrap you code as (assuming this is Query1):

```
try
  let
  ....

  in
  ...

otherwise
  "Error"
```

and then having one error wrapping query for all queries as:

```
if Query1 = "Error" then "Error" 
else if Query2 = "Error" then  "Error"
...
else "No Error"
```

which you can then load to Excel as a new sheet and check with VBA macro whether the value of such a cell contains "Error" or not.

Comment: Wrapping `try...otherwise` around the M query is an interesting way of handing it.  I want future readers to know that this method hides all the power query *steps* so for debugging you won't be able to see the actual error until you remove the try...otherwise.
Also be aware that returning an error instead of your expected query columns may mess up the formatting on the sheet by inserting columns to the left of the table.  Correcting the error does not restore the column positions so things can get messy.

Comment: What I like to do, is have VBA Clear out all the results in the query tables. So that there is only one row. I usually expect more rows to be present after a refresh. So I check whether there are more rows after the refresh using VBA.