# How to force Power Query to clear caches to get accurate performance metrics

Tags: excel, vba, logging, caching, powerquery

I have set up a small VBA macro to run all queries in a workbook and log the time taken for each one. It works for the first test, however every subsequent test takes less than a second. I suspect Power Query is caching the result of the queries and not running the full query like it does the first time. Is there a way to force Power Query to run each query as if they have not been refreshed recently?

The below code refreshes each query and saves the time taken to an array. Note: I'm aware there are probably better ways to get more accurate timing, but right now I am trying to solve the caching issue.

```
        For Each conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
            If InStr(1, conn.Name, "Query - test_") = 1 Then

                Debug.Print "Refreshing " & conn.Name

                connBgStatus = conn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery 'Save current background-refresh value
                conn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False 'Temporarily disable background-refresh

                startTime = Timer
                conn.Refresh
                endTime = Timer

                conn.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = connBgStatus 'Set background-refresh value back to original value

                returnArr(i, 0) = testID & "_" & Format(i + 1, "000")
                returnArr(i, 1) = conn.Name
                returnArr(i, 2) = endTime - startTime

                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
```

This right now outputs the below
[image: Output]

Comment: You could parameterise your queries so that some input critical to the `Source` step is defined in a cell, e.g. table name/folder path etc. In your code you could add a trailing character to the parameter, to cause an `Expression error` in PQ. Since VBA can't trap this you might use try/otherwise in PQ (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55022299)), and 'wait' for `Error` to appear in a specific cell - then you could remove the trailing character from your parameter, and then the connection can be refreshed without the 'benefit' of caching.

Comment: If you're querying from a database then there may be other caches involved: eg. the OS caches the database connection, the database server caches/pins your query.  Try running the queries in your database's query tool and see if you see a difference between the first and subsequent runs.

Comment: Querying from a CSV, so that isn’t the issue. Good suggestion though

Comment: @SpectralInstance, will try this when I’m back in work to verify that it’s definitely a caching problem. Unfortunately I was hoping for a purely vba solution since I was wanting to be able to drop in other queries to test without editing them.

Comment: Note files on disk can also be cached (at least on Windows)

Comment: Files are on a file server (not sure which particular OS my work uses). I wouldn't have thought that would affect the Power Query speeds though. When you open the same file twice it isn't any faster, so I doubt that Power Query is getting a cached faster version.